# Creating a Query String HTML form that passes through pages?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I am very new to dev and probably biting off more than I chew right now. :0

I am looking to create a query string form that will stick through a users session, no matter what backpages they travel between during the visit.

This is what i got so far, its not much, but It does accomplish some of what I'm trying to do.

```
<div style="text-align: center;"> 
<form method="get" action="http://www.example.com"> 
<input name="n" value="Show" type="hidden"> 
<input name="id"> <input type="submit"> 
</form> </div>
```

This code builds the form and send the user to the custom submitted query link after entry, however, I would like the custom query to stick all pages they visit. In this code the query is only valid for the initial page after entry.
Need the query stay attached to child pages thereafter as well: IE: http://example.com/blob/?id=44553355 as well as http://example.com/blog/article/?id=44553355

Any suggestions on how to tweak the form or accomplish this task I would very much appreciate it. 
Thank you.

Comment: Use session to pass the values to other subsequent pages.

Comment: Use [sessions](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) with a variable `$_SESSION['id']` and forget about the query string

Answer (score 0):

start a session and store what you need in it

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['query']='Query goes here';
```

When the user hits a point where you no longer want them to have the link remove the variable from the session and end it.

```
unset($_SESSION['link']);
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Embarrassed to admit this, but i don't know how to implement this! I'm sure it is the correct way to accomplish this (2 others also suggested this above) but i don't know what to do with it unfortunately. Using wordpress btw. Thanks for your answer...